# Codeigniter pagination with web service

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

So I was wondering if it's possible to use Codeigniter's pagination when using a Web Service? We're using REST and since we're not connecting to a database per se, I was wondering how I would handle the total rows call required in the pagination setup?

Comment: This is a great question but you should provide more details for a good response. is this your web service or ??? is the web service giving you a total results?

Comment: We're using Docusign. I'm getting a response and can get the parts I need to display on the page but since all the tutorials/forum posts are using models to connect to a database, I'm not sure how to handle the total rows configuration. The total rows would change also.

Comment: please follow up if pveyes suggestion worked or not?

Comment: It has not so far. I'm working on another section of the interface, but will try again over the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I managed to implement it:

```
//My array to hold the envelope data
$displayArray = $data['response']['envelopes'];

// The pagination controller code
$quantity = 15;
$start = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['displayArray'] = array_slice($displayArray,$start,$quantity);
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite.com/lcb/status/index/';
$config['total_rows'] = count($displayArray);
$config['per_page'] = $quantity;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$this->load->view('envelope_status', $data);

// Code for view
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<div id="container">
    <h1>History</h1>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Envelope ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Date</th></tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($displayArray as $envelope) { ?>
                <tr cellpadding="2"><td style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $envelope["envelopeId"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $envelope["status"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $envelope["statusChangedDateTime"]; ?></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

So there you have it. I still need to see about getting it to display them in newest-to-oldest order, instead of the reverse, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get total number of item you need to fetch, and some items in specific index (eg. id=5 to id=10), You can use codeigniter pagination library

Below is example (in your controller):

```
<?php
   public function some_page($current_page)
   {
      $per_page = 5; // example
      $current_index = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;
      $your_item_list = $this->YOUR_API->get_item_list($current_index, $per_page);

      $config['total_rows'] = $this->YOUR_API->get_total_rows();
      $config['per_page'] = $item_per_page;        
      $this->load->library('pagination', $config);
   }
?>
```

Or you could use a trick, fetch all data then use `count()` and `array_slice()`

```
<?php
   $all_items = $this->YOUR_API->get_all_items();
   $item_list = array_slice($all_item, $current_index, $per_page);
   $config['total_rows'] = count($all_items);
?>
```

Comment: This indeed does not work. I'm getting three errors: (1) $current_page in not defined, so that throws up the usual undefined variable error, (2) no matter what I put in for the "YOUR_API", I get an undefined property error and (3) I get the "Call to a member function get_item_list() on a non-object" error.